# How to get more content in-game?

Tags: trackmania-2

Since I've bought TrackMania 2 Stadium on Steam a few days ago I've come to understand one can spend in-game currency to buy tracks, models and skins, but I can't figure out how...
I've managed to add some courses through the Steam workshop, but I think there's supposed to be a way from within the game.

Is there? How?

Comment: I think you can do that when playing on someone's server, at least in the playmania version you can buy other people's tracks for planets if they have them for sale.

Comment: A Google search for "playmania trackmania" goes back to this page... Did you mean ManiaPlanet? I think the Steam version is fully compatible with ManiaPlanet.

Comment: Yes I meant maniaplanet, sorry. I haven't played trackmania that much but I think if you play on someone's server they can sell you their tracks for planets (the ingame currency). It's like that for shootmania, and with the whole maniaplanet thing they are trying to normalize their competitive games, so it would be odd if it was any different for trackmania.

Answer (score 1):

If you want tracks, you can download them from TMX "Trackmania Exchange". You said you have steam version. Yes you can download products which were published to steam workshop such as skins, tracks, and other things. If you want acces to ingame store, you have to know special manialink, which opens a ingame store. Stores are usually made by players. You can download skins, avatars, horns,tracks and mods from there. But you have to pay with your planets, which is your ingame currency.

Comment: Do you have a link to the TMX site? Or is it just on steam? You put links in your answers. That always increases the value of your answers. (But don't just linkdump answers, explain what the link does/says/contains as well).

Comment: Here's the [TMX](http://www.tm-exchange.com/) link